# neo4j: creating the same relationship towards multiple nodes using neo4j-restclient

Tags: python-2.7, neo4j, neo4jrestclient

Using the Python `neo4j-restclient`, I'm trying to find out if I can simplify the creation of the same relationship emanating from the same node to different nodes. So currently, I have

```
alice = g.nodes.create(name='Alice')
bob = g.nodes.create(name='Bob')
chuck = g.nodes.create(name='Chuck')
darryl = g.nodes.create(name='Darryl')
eve = g.nodes.create(name='Eve')

alice.relationships.create("is friends with", bob)
alice.relationships.create("is friends with", chuck)
alice.relationships.create("is friends with", darryl)
alice.relationships.create("is friends with", eve)
```

Is there any simpler way to do this, without having to invoke `relationships.create` a dozen times?

Comment: Consider using Cypher: `MATCH (alice:Person {name:'Alice'}), (friend:Person) WHERE friend.name in ["Bob","Chuck","Darryl","Eve] MERGE (alice)-[:friend_of]->(friend)`

Answer (score 0):

I would use a Cypher query or a batch-based transaction for that.

```
with g.transaction():
    alice = g.nodes.create(name='Alice')
    for name in ["Bob","Chuck","Darryl","Eve"]:
        friend = g.nodes.create(name=name)
        alice.relationships.create("is friends with", friend)
```

Or even without the transaction.